# iOS Microphone sampling doesn't work on device when mixing CoreAudio and OpenAL code

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording, microphone, openal

I tried writing an app that samples the microphone using code from http://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/ (Core Audio),
and plays sounds using code from https://github.com/hollance/SoundBankPlayer (OpenAL).

This works fine when running on simulator, but when testing on a real device - microphone sampling doesn't work (the recordingCallback in the IosAudioController never gets called).

When I disable the SoundBankPlayer code (do not instantiate a new SoundBankPlayer, therefore no OpenAL code is used), the microphone sampling works just fine.

Is there a known limitation of mixing OpenAL and Core Audio code in the same project? If so - is there a workaround? If not - what else could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out I had to change the audio session category from `kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback` to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` when initializing the audio session in the OpenAL code.